# Calculate SHA1 sum of file with GnuPG on OS X

Tags: gnupg, macos

I'm looking at the [GnuPG download page](https://www.gnupg.org/download/integrity_check.html), that's telling me that I can check the hash sum of a file with the following command:

```
sha1sum apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M1-src.tar
```

This unfortunately does not work, and results in a command not found error. I have installed GnuPG with brew, (`brew install gpg`) and I know that GnuPG is installed on my machine. I have tried many options, such as `gpg -sha1sum apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M1-src.tar` etc, but nothing has worked so far.

How can I calculate the SHA1 hash of my file?

Comment: sha1sum isn't part of GPG. That page is just saying you can use it on your GPG download - same as you can use it on any other download.

Answer (score 2):

While Linux distributions often bring tools dedicated to calculate given hashsums like `sha1sum` and `sha256sum`, OS X does not have those. But OpenSSL is available and readily installed, and can be used for calculating hash sums, similarly to how `sha1sum` is used:

```
openssl sha1 apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M1-src.tar
```

Comment: is your gpg version missing the `--print-md` command?

Comment: I knew I missed something. Don't ask me how I was able to overlook this going through both man pages and autocompletion for `gpg` and `gpg2`... I'll remove the wrong paragraph, but leave the rest available (as on one hand OpenSSL is preinstalled, and on the other hand provides a more common lowercase output without space separators).

Answer (score 2):

Please use

```
gpg --print-md sha1 filename
```

to get the same output format as `sha1sum` use

```
gpg --print-md sha1 filename | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' | sed -r 's/([A-F0-9]{4})(\ *|\n)/\L\1/g'|sed  -r 's/(.*):\ (.*)/\2\ \ \1/g'
```

should be BSD sed compatible. Also works for sha256 and sha512

Answer (score 0):

sha1sum is separate from GPG.  If you don't have sha1sum on your system, you can install it.  See https://raam.org/2008/howto-install-md5sum-sha1sum-on-mac-os-x/ for more info.

Or, you can use openssl instead, to compute a sha1 hash of a file, like so:

```
openssl dgst -sha1 filename
```